Avoid closures when calling Parallel.For()
I'm performing some element UI hit testing like this:
internal MyElement[] HitTest((double x, double y) point, double scale) 
{
    ConcurrentBag<MyElement> geoms = new ConcurrentBag<MyElement>();

    var point = new Point { X = point.x, Y = point.y };

    Parallel.For(0,UIElements.Length, (d) =>
    {
        var element = UIElements[d];
        if (element is IHitTestable ht && ht.HitTest(ref point,scale) geoms.Add(element);
    });

    return geoms.ToArray();
}

I would like to refactor this to remove closures around local variables; also I believe that each iteration of the loop might be allocating anonymous stuff (classes,methods) per each iteration.
The issue is that the Parallel.For() parameters expect an Action<int> as a delegate to run in parallel, whereas I need a delegate Action<int,Point,double> to handle the local variables so that I can write a compile-time method with the expected argument types.
How do I provide Parallel.For() with an appropriate delegate without anonymity?
I believe this problem could be embarassingly parallel, but it will not be if there is competition for the heap.
@PanagiotisKanavos asks what I'm trying to do; implement a hit-testing algorithm against a flat array of UI elements. I was approaching like this:

Write the above method, which is iteration of all UIElements in the array and hit test each item (knowing it's not optimal)
...refactor to pass a rectangle of the current viewport to the method, create a slice of the array elements within the viewport by performing a fast cull, and hit test the sliced elements. I'm thinking this will be optimized enough, especially combined with other tricks (for example, SIMD to compare viewport rect to each element rect)
The third milestone would be to implement a specialized data structure (quadtree, etc) if the above optimizations are not enough and performance is not acceptable. (avoid premature optimization)


Don’t suppose the motivating problem is the type that would be better solved by introducing a hierarchy of bounding boxes that would reduce the number of UI elements you have to call HitTest on in the first place?

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to avoid allocation here. Not with C# anyway. Even if you spin your own threads you have to communicate with them somehow. And this means queue with heap allocated data. Well, you could preallocate some data for that queue I suppose. On the other hand you use a bag and .ToArray() call at the end. These are likely to dominate closure allocation anyway. I don't think what you are trying to achieve is worth it at all.

Btw, classes and methods are not being allocated. These exist from the beginning and are immutable (well, that's not 100% true, e.g. reflection and jitting, but it's irrelevant here). The only thing getting allocated is closure, i.e. an object containing all catched variables.

What is the ​UIElements? Is it a field of type MyElement[] in the enclosing class? How many elements is it expected to have approximately?

Instead of paralleling, place the UIElements in a quadtree for a quick search.

What is this code trying to do? A spatial index would improve performance far more than parallelization. Parallelizing inefficient code won't outperform code using the correct algorithms. Besides, given this code, you probably want Parallel LINQ, not PFOR, eg UIElements.AsParallel().Where(p=>p.HitTest(point,scale)).ToArray() Spatial libraries like NetTopologySuite contain several index types that could help

As JonasH wrote, don't make assumptions. Capture isn't a concern in this code unless .HitTest modifies point. It would be better if HitTest did not use ref, so that point would be copied by value (assuming it's a struct). Delegates aren't allocated per iteration. To avoid capture just copy the values inside the delegate, eg var local_scale=scale; var local_point=point;. You won't gain much from this though. Using an index will offer far greater benefits

If the hit test is slow, you can also calculate a bounding rect beforehand and save it separately. It is easy and fast (SIMD) to iterate over an array of Rectangles to check if they include a point. Then do the slow hit check only if the bounding rect has a hit.

So is it correct to say that only one Action<int> delegate anonymous method is allocated, and this delegate does not create any more allocations during the closure around the point or the scale values per each iteration?

@DasKrümelmonster can you give some references on SIMD rect comparisons? I'm assuming two path options forward is 1. build and maintain a quadtree 2. Keep with flat iteration, but optimize first by culling elements outside of bounds (where it seems SIMD would help)

@NWoodsman you really, really need to explain what you're doing because you're down the wrong path. SIMD operations process multiple data in a single CPU operation. They're at least 4,8 or 16 times faster than parallelism BUT ... using a proper index structure is faster. And the index itself can use SIMD and parallelism. BUT the hit test on rectangular shapes or envelopes is essentially a comparison operation, which is very fast.

That means that just sorting the envelopes by X and doing a range search may end up being faster than parallelism or a a quad tree, because it works on data that's probably already in the CPU cache. 1000 envelopes with 4 coordinates each is NOT a lot. You could use eg Vector.GreaterThan to compare 4 or more values at once, depending on your CPU's register size. Once you find possible matches, you can start using the more expensive HitTest to check each of them

@PanagiotisKanavos your last comment applies to me. I thought optimizing a flat structure with parallelism, tricks, etc would be sufficiently optimal to avoid implementing a specialized structure. If SIMD is competitive, I will investigate that approach.


I believe that each iteration of the loop might be allocating anonymous stuff (classes,methods) per each iteration.

Only a single delegate object will be created when the Parallel.For is called. This will capture any local variables, but calling the delegate will not cause any further allocations. So the overhead for this should be fixed, and likely insignificant if a parallel loop is warranted.
There will be some overhead in making the call to the delegate, accessing fields etc. So for parallel loops with small bodies it is common to have an inner regular loop to spread this cost over multiple items.

How do I provide Parallel.For() with an appropriate delegate without anonymity

There are a bunch of options, you could create a local method, but the main advantage of that is giving the method a real name to improve readability. You could create a member method, but that would require you to store the parameters as fields in your class, and that is probably not a good idea. You could also create an object of a custom class, and pass a member method of that object, but that would be equivalent to what the compiler does for you.

if there is competition for the heap.

I'm unable to find a source, but I'm fairly sure there is a per-thread segment of memory to service small allocations. So synchronization should only be needed when this segment is filled. This would ofc only be relevant if the threads made allocations.
In general I would highly recommend to profile and/or benchmark the code before making any assumptions about performance. If there are 'few' (say hundreds) items a regular loop will probably be best, since it avoids any synchronization overhead of a parallel loop. If there are lots of items (say millions), you might want to reconsider your approach, since UI framework tend to have problems handling that many objects.

​My understanding is that the OP is worried not about the allocation of the closure object, but about the cost of dereferencing the fields of this object. They would prefer if for example the scale was a local variable in the thread's stack, instead of being a field of an object that lives in the heap.

@TheodorZoulias I was worried it was both 1. an allocation of a thousand unique anonymous delegates because of the closure and 2. a synchronization pressure during those thousand allocations competing for the heap.

@NWoodsman you could edit the question and include this information there. You might want to expand on what you mean by "synchronization pressure" and "competition for the heap".

These things are no more important in brute force searching, than worrying about parallelizing lookups when Dictionaries and HashSets are available. The real gotcha is that if the elements are rectangular, the hit tests are just comparisons which are very fast. And even if they aren't, they should be - in 2D and spatial algorithms, using a bounding rectangle can be used to improve performance immensely. It's at this point that heaps and references start playing a role, because they're compared against plain old comparisons

And yes, before anyone says, I've done this for big things going boom drawn on ArcObjects maps. One can't just make assumptions.

@PanagiotisKanavos see motivation I added to the post.

What Parallel.For() essentially does is
for (int i = fromInclusive; i < toExclusive; i++) {
    action(i); // somehow in parallel
}

what you would want it to do is:
for (int i = fromInclusive; i < toExclusive; i++) {
    action(i, point, double); // somehow in parallel
}

For this to be possible for your case, the authors of the class would have had to make an overload of Parallel.For like this (and for all other possible use cases):
public static ParallelLoopResult For(int fromInclusive, 
int toExclusive, Action<int,Point,double> action, Point point, double body)

Maybe they could have provided a general overload accepting Action<int,object> where you could use object to pass all arguments in a custom object.
public static ParallelLoopResult For(int fromInclusive, 
int toExclusive, Action<int,object> action, object state)

It will do this:
for (int i = fromInclusive; i < toExclusive; i++) {
    action(i, state); // somehow in parallel
}

Then you could have achieved what you want by having a dedicated method with a signature like this and cast the object inside to the custom object of your needs so, you can use the needed fields that have useful state for the iteration:
void DoStuffInParrallel(int index, object state)
   CustomObject customObject = (CustomObject) state;
   ....

then you can do that somewhat conveniently (most of what you requested in the question)
 CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();
 customObject.state1 = ...
 Parallel.For(0,1,DoStuffInParallel, customObject)

Unfortunately, there is no such overload. for Parallel.For that accepts Action<int,object>
So you are essentially forced to have state available somehow in a method which doesn't allow state as parameter.
Given that constraint, closures actually help us a lot in passing state to the method in a way that we would have most likely implemented ourselves.
The compiler creates a hidden class that would have been the object we needed to pass in the non-available overload with Action<int,object>.  The implementation for a case very similar to yours is (I've tested in LINQPad so a bit of changes here and there):
private sealed class ClosureClass {

    public UserQuery enclosingScopeThis; // this would be the class type that  has UIElements as member in your case
    public Point pointToCapture;
    public double scale;
    public ConcurrentBag<MyElement> geoms;

    internal void Lambda(int index) {
        MyElement element = enclosingScopeThis.UIElements[index];
        if (element.HitTest(ref pointToCapture, scale)) {
            geoms.Add(element);
        }
    }
}

It also has created the Action<int> instance method Lambda (my name, not the compiler's) that represents our lambda that has access to the state we wanted via the instance fields of the class.
This new hidden class is used by the compiler to actually rewrite your method into something similar to this:
public MyElement[] HitTest((double x, double y) point, double scale) {
    
    ClosureClass closureInstance = new ClosureClass();
    // all local variables that are "captured" become instance fields
    // of the compiler generated ClosureClass
    closureInstance.enclosingScopeThis = this;
    closureInstance.geoms = new ConcurrentBag<MyElement>();
    closureInstance.pointToCapture = new Point { X = point.x, Y = point.y };

    Action<int> lambdaToPass = closureInstance.Lambda;
    
    Parallel.For(0, UIElements.Length, lambdaToPass);

    return closureInstance.geoms.ToArray();
}

So, only one ClosureClass instance is allocated.
You can verify this exactly for your use case if you use ILSpy with "IL with C#" selected.
You can also rewrite the code manually using the same (or similar) logic to visualize what is going on. If you don't find problems with it, i.e. you would have done the same, don't refactor.
Now the issue here as it would be had you done this by hand is that the closure class (with its fields) is now shared state between the different threads that execute in parallel.
This part of your code is problematic in my opinion
ht.HitTest(ref point,scale)

Probably point is a struct and we want to pass it faster, but with ref we have no guarantees that it won't change inside the method.
If you don't mutate point inside (as the name suggests that you don't have to), consider rewriting the method to:
ht.HitTest(in point,scale)

It will still be passed by reference but with guarantees that it cannot be mutated inside the method which will eliminate all possible shared-state problems for this.
